# How can I create a new model that is an extention of an existing model with an additional field

Tags: extjs4

Currently the additional field is calculted in the grid columnCfgs using an xtype of templatecolumn. I need to add this field to the grid data store so that it can be used to filter the grid data.

Comment: What have you tried? Last time I tried extending a model and adding more fields to it, it worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model classes `fields` property is processed in a special fashion. Instead of replacing the parent class' ones as a normal property would, child fields are appended to them.

See this example:

```
Ext.define('Base', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model'
    ,fields: ['foo','bar']
});

Ext.define('Extended', {
    extend: 'Base'
    ,fields: ['baz']
});

var record = Ext.create('Extended');

record.fields.each(function(field) {
    console.log(field.name);
});
```

That gives the following output:

```
foo
bar
id
baz
```

Comment: Thank You! I was trying the setField method, but your example is simpler and works perfectly!